# Public Maven JAR artifact with stubs for android.os.Build and android.util.Log

Tags: java, android, maven, android-library

I develop a Java library that runs on the JVM as well as on Android. On Android, I use the classes `android.os.Build` and `android.util.Log`. Currently, I compile against `com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4`, which is very outdated.

Unfortunately, there are no newer version of the Android artifact in the Central Maven repository. As I know, Google moved to its own Maven repository: https://maven.google.com/.

However, I cannot find there any Maven artifact that contains stubs for `android.os.Build` and `android.util.Log`. Where can I find a maintained Maven artifact with stubs for both classes?

Comment: They should be part of of the Android SDK. Forch each traget platform version a stub android.jar can be downloaded via Android SDK manager. AFAIR the correct jar is automatically downloaded by Android Gradle Plugin. Maven is not a supported build platform foran Android library.

Comment: I hoped secretly that there would be a simpler solution. Switching from Maven to Gradle and downloading the entire Android SDK sounds like an overkill when only a stub of a handful of Android classes is needed.

Comment: I don't remember any changes in the two classes you use. So if the current way works you can keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [`org.robolectric/android-all`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.robolectric/android-all), from [robolectric.org](https://robolectric.org/), a framework that allows you to run Android tests directly on the JVM. It included [stubs for many Android classes](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/commit/880a03694c4bebc56ff9b88d8b9496aaa5d52562).

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-all</artifactId>
    <version>14-robolectric-10818077</version> <!-- Check for the latest version -->
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Remember, Robolectric is primarily intended for testing, so it is included with the `test` scope. If you need these stubs for non-testing purposes, you may need to adjust the scope or find an alternative solution.

Note that, for Android development, it is generally recommended to use Android Studio and its integrated Gradle system, which has direct access to Android's Maven repository. That approach would provide you with the most up-to-date and compatible libraries for Android development.

Comment: org.robolectric:robolectric nor any of its dependency contain the Android classes I need. However, I found what I need in org.robolectric:android-all.

Comment: @Martin Good catch. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try to this step:

```
android.os.Build and android.util.Log
```

**below step first follows**

1. Open android Studio -> File -> invalid and cache restart
2. Build -> Clean Project and after that rebuild project
3. File -> Setting -> Search on Gradle and set Java17 amazon
4. File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Android Gradle plugin Version 8.1.1 and gradle version 8.0
5. then Go to the Setting.Gradles file

   repositories {
   google()
   mavenCentral()
   gradlePluginPortal()
   }
6. gradle properties open file ->

   android.useAndroidX=true,
   android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
7. Tool option clicked -> AGP Upgrade assistant -> Select 8.1.2 then Run selected step and Refress.
8. Build.gradle(module.app) open file and API level 34.

namespace = "com.flora.ordertracker"

compileSdk = 34

```
minSdk = 24
```

targetSdk = 34

versionCode = 1